# GeoDjango / PostGIS - Cut geometry by bounding box

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geodjango

I am looking for a solution to retrieve the geometry(ies) from a polygon/multipolygon within a bounding box in a GeoDjango application.

The application I am developing has a requirement to serve out tiles of geographical data, and many of our geometries are very large and span across multiple tiles. To reduce the payload of each tile I would like to splice(cut) a geometry shape(s) from a bounding box.

I am storing Planet.OSM data in a PostGIS database.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a GeoQuerySet, you can call the [intersection() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeoQuerySet.intersection) with a geometry argument (e.g. your bounding box) to return the geometries from your GeoQuerySet that are intersected by the geometry (bounding box) you provided. If you need to use a raw query, try the corresponding [ST_Intersection method of PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Intersection.html). In either case, you should initially filter your results to those that are intersected by the bounding box. To quote the [ST_Intersection reference](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Intersection.html):

> ST_Intersection in conjunction with ST_Intersects is very useful for clipping geometries such as in bounding box, buffer, region queries where you only want to return that portion of a geometry that sits in a country or region of interest.